# Difficulties getting a Return to Libc attack working with strange errors

Tags: return-value, buffer-overflow

This is a project for an information security course in my masters program wherein we implement a variety of buffer overflow attacks. One of which being Return to lib-c.
The server runs on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-139-generic x86_64).
The attack is performed on the following code, with the goal being to execute a shell.
The version of GDB that is being used does not have access to the find command.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *signatures[] = {"sys_open_ports", "sys_module", "write_binaries"};

int is_virus(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        char traffic[64];
        int i, j, len;

        traffic[0] = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
                strcat(traffic, argv[i]);

        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                len = strlen(signatures[j]);
                for (i = 0; i < (int)strlen(traffic); ++i)
                        if (strncmp(signatures[j], traffic+i, len) == 0)
                                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        if (argc < 2) {
                system("echo 'usage: target3 network_traffic_packets'");
                exit(1);
        }

        if (is_virus(argc, argv))
                printf("Alarm! virus founded\n");
        else
                printf("safe.\n");

        return 0;
```

Based on guides online, I determined the most important steps were to determine how much it takes to overwrite the return address, the address of system, the address of exit, and the address of `/bin/sh`.

I entered GDB and used p system and p exit to get their associated addresses as being 0x4005d97c and 0x40049cdc respectively. [P system return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqUgM.png)[P exit return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufUdx.png)

Since I don't have the find command, I used # export "SHELL=/bin/sh" to ensure it is around and then used x/500s $esp until I found the address which came out to 0xbffffc09[/bin/sh address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObhTd.png)
Since this address has the SHELL=, I adjusted it by 6 to 0xbffffc0F to skip those values.

Lastly, I determined the buffer needed through testing. I found that 74 A's in the buffer did not overwrite the return,
[Buffer size test 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACklM.png)

whereas 78 A's completely overwrote it,
[Buffer size test 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzckT.png)

Given all of this information, I decided that I the attack string should be:

```
r 10 `python -c 'print("A"*74) + "\x7c\xd9\x05\x40" + "\xdc\x9c\x04\x40" + "\x0F\xfc\xff\xbf"'`
```

The 10 is used to pass the argc < 2 check, the A * 74 is used to fill the buffer so that we next overwrite return, "\x7c\xd9\x05\x40" is the address of the system as determined by p system, \xdc\x9c\x04\x40" is the address of exit as determined by p exit, and lastly "\x0F\xfc\xff\xbf" is the address of the /bin/bash string for the system to call.
Running this returns [Running it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze0Tf.png)
with a strange strcat in libc segmentation fault.

In testing, I thought maybe I had flipped the exit and /bin/bash and so I tested reversing them which returns [Running it 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrdfp.png)
A different error that seemed to maybe launch a shell but I am not sure.
I tried running both of the above tests with various buffer sizes from 70 to 78 and those just return segmentation faults.

Any help would be appreciated, I have communicated with the TA for the course and he is not sure what the issue is either or at least did not communicate it if he was.